# Inno Setup deletes my changes in the Uninstall registry key when I do un update of an existing installation

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry, inno-setup, updates

I'm using Inno Setup for my application. The setup is used for the installation AND for the upgrade (when I launch it, if it found an older install it check if it's possible to upgrade...)

I would like to know at what step Inno Setup write Keys in the Registry, because even if the installation is failed I found the keys in registry.

At the end of the installation I add other values to my installation key in the registry (added using a .bat script at the postinstall...)

And, when I do un update of my installation, Inno Setup delete my old key and delete my changes.

So, what is the best practice to set keys in registry with Inno Setup ?
What should I do to keep my key in the registry without changes by Inno Setup at the update ?

I don't use the `[registry]` section

[EDIT]

**Example:**
When I do the first installation of my application, the setup (created with Inno Setup) stores values (InstallLocation, Version ...) in the registry here:

```
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{myApp_guid}_is1"
```

And on the postInstall, using a .bat script I add other informations like URLs or Path to other programs...

So, when I do `reg query` I have something like this:
reg query

```
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{myApp_guid}_is1"

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{myApp_guid}_is1
    Inno Setup: Setup Version    REG_SZ    6.0.3 (u)
    Inno Setup: App Path    REG_SZ    my_path
    InstallLocation    REG_SZ    my_path
    Inno Setup: Icon Group    REG_SZ    NameGroup
    Inno Setup: User    REG_SZ    User
    Inno Setup: Language    REG_SZ    english
    DisplayName    REG_SZ    Name App with version
    DisplayIcon    REG_SZ    my_icon_path
    UninstallString    REG_SZ    "my_uninstall_path"
    QuietUninstallString    REG_SZ    "my_unistall_path" /SILENT
    DisplayVersion    REG_SZ    1.0.0
    Publisher    REG_SZ    Publisher
    URLInfoAbout    REG_SZ    URL
    HelpLink    REG_SZ    URL Help
    URLUpdateInfo    REG_SZ    Url
    NoModify    REG_DWORD    0x1
    NoRepair    REG_DWORD    0x1
    InstallDate    REG_SZ    20200925
    MajorVersion    REG_DWORD    0x1
    MinorVersion    REG_DWORD    0x0
    VersionMajor    REG_DWORD    0x1
    VersionMinor    REG_DWORD    0x0
    EstimatedSize    REG_DWORD    0x3a04
    HERE_URL_curstom REG_SZ link
    HERE_PATH_TO_ANOTHER_PROGRAM REG_SZ path
```

But, When I launch the Setup again (to do un update of my application), it delete the changes made during the postinstall (URLs, Path to other programs..) in the registry.
SO, when I do `reg query` I have something like:

```
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{myApp_guid}_is1"

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{myApp_guid}_is1
    Inno Setup: Setup Version    REG_SZ    6.0.3 (u)
    Inno Setup: App Path    REG_SZ    my_path
    InstallLocation    REG_SZ    my_path
    Inno Setup: Icon Group    REG_SZ    NameGroup
    Inno Setup: User    REG_SZ    User
    Inno Setup: Language    REG_SZ    english
    DisplayName    REG_SZ    Name App with version
    DisplayIcon    REG_SZ    my_icon_path
    UninstallString    REG_SZ    "my_uninstall_path"
    QuietUninstallString    REG_SZ    "my_unistall_path" /SILENT
    DisplayVersion    REG_SZ    1.0.0
    Publisher    REG_SZ    Publisher
    URLInfoAbout    REG_SZ    URL
    HelpLink    REG_SZ    URL Help
    URLUpdateInfo    REG_SZ    Url
    NoModify    REG_DWORD    0x1
    NoRepair    REG_DWORD    0x1
    InstallDate    REG_SZ    20200925
    MajorVersion    REG_DWORD    0x1
    MinorVersion    REG_DWORD    0x0
    VersionMajor    REG_DWORD    0x1
    VersionMinor    REG_DWORD    0x0
    EstimatedSize    REG_DWORD    0x3a04
```

*Without the 2 last values

So I would know at what time at did that and why Inno Setup don't keep my changes in `"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{myApp_guid}_is1"`

To do the update, I don't execute the script that I use for the first install and where I do the edit of my key in registry.

Thanks

Comment: If you have a look into the help for registry keys you will see there is a flag that will only set the value if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl great, thank you ! It's what I'm looking for